# PHP Mail on Windows Server too slow

Tags: php, windows, email

How can I speed up the processing time of my php mail function that is based on a Windows Server? I've found some hack to be done on the hostname, but seems applicable to linux-based config only. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update your Server and install SSL Certificate then restart and its faster